# How could someone survive in the Quantum Realm?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, ant-man-and-the-wasp

In *Ant-Man and the Wasp*, how did

> Janet Van Dyne live in the Quantum Realm? How did she get the hood, the spear... the makeup?

Do they explain it in the movie?

Comment: By “spear”, do you mean the thing strapped to her back? I think that was a wing from her Wasp suit. Presumably the hood was made from whatever she was wearing under the suit. And as for make-up, she’s Michelle Pfieffer! She just looks like that!

Comment: Pym Particles? Isn't that usually the go to answer in the Marvel Universe?

Comment: The Quantum Realm?  Hmm. it's uncertain....

Comment: Easily! She just hung around for 30 years, and was really careful to not catch a quantum zombie virus. Job done.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

While in the Quantum Realm, you catch a glimpse of a city in the background encased in a dome. Possible she could acquire those items and food / whatever there.

[image: Quantum Realm City]

Comment: thanks Jack.. I can now die in peace...

Comment: I'd LOVE to know if they're gonna do something with that, if that's indeed a "city" as it appears to be.

Comment: I LOVE THE CITY IN THE QUANTUM REALM THING.

Comment: I have been thinking the same thing. I will be furious if the city is not the MAIN focus of the 3rd Antman.

Comment: Almost certainly populated entirely by [Micronauts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Micronauts#Comic_books).

Answer (score 7):

Nothing is explained.

It appears that some propery of the Quantum Realm manifests as some sort of healing energy. This is presumably what sustains Janet.

> this is what Janet uses to help Ava in the conclusion

We know there's some sort of mental connection involving the Quantum Realm. Perhaps this also allows Janet to manipulate her environment, making it livable and creating clothes etc.

In general, there's no science or logic to what happens in Ant Man. You just have to accept the premise that there's this cool size-changing stuff that works however the writers need it to, and go with it. It's superhero Action/Comedy/Drama, not SciFi.

Comment: I was very keen to see how she would be like after living for decades in another realm per se and I can't say about most people but this was kind of a bummer for me. 

Jack B Nimble up there has a good answer

Answer (score -3):

I think the answer is hidden in the word "EVOLUTION". Van Dyne uses this word when she says, "this place changes you". I think she means that since time and space work very differently in the Quantum Realm, then the way we humans evolve would work differently too. Somehow her mind and her body evolved to survive the new ecosystem she had to survive in. This is one thing we humans are good at - adapting & surviving and these two things bring evolution.

This fascinates me because of a free VSauce YouTube Red MindField episode I watched a few days ago. This [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ktkjUjcZid0) talks about a theory that seems appropriate.

Comment: Well, technically, evolution happens by genetic changes that make someone more likely to survive and pass on those genes to new generations. So, unless this is Janet Van Dyne the 47th, who just somehow thinks shes the original, not technically evolution in the scientific sense.

Answer (score -3):

There is no reason they couldn’t. The dangers, she could learn to avoid. She might have interacted with people living there.